# How to solve 'Cannot start Scala compile server' for Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I am new in using Scala and Intellij Idea. This error message occured after i update the new version of intellij idea Community. can anyone help me for this error? I've been trying for a week by searching in here but the solution does not help. I'm really don't know what should i do

> 2:35 PM   Cannot start Scala compile server: JDK for compiler process not found: Unexpected sdk type: 'IDEA JDK' for sdk IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition IC-211.7142.45: version 16 (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/212.5284.40)

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it by unticking the "Use compile server" checkbox!

[image: Untick the "Use compile server" checkbox]